# Figures generated with pgfplots and includestandalone do not have the same size, even though the scaling is equal

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

In my project I have several graphs/figures displaying data. The requirements I got are to use the same font in the text of the main document and in all figures. Therefore, I decided to use pgfplots/tikz for drawing my graphs, but encountered several issues.

When including two figures which were generated the same way (see below) and using the same width, their height was not equal (as shown in the figure below). Why is that, and how can I force them to become equal in size (heigth and width)?

To demonstrate the problem, I created a small MWE below. It uses three files, `main.tex`, `sub.tex` and `sub2.tex`:
main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    5 5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.dat}
    x y
    0 0
    1 1
    2 4
    3 9
    4 16
    5 25
    6 36
    7 49
    8 64
    9 81
    10 100
    11 121
    12 144
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\LARGE\bfseries},
        tick label style={font=\LARGE}  
    },
    y axis/.append style={align=center}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
            \includestandalone[width=\linewidth, mode=buildnew,
            ]{sub}\caption{Image I}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
            \includestandalone[width=\linewidth, mode=buildnew,
            ]{sub2}\caption{Image II}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

sub.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{file1.dat}{\tablea}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
                \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0, ymax=30,
            xmin=0, xmax=5,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            grid=major,
            legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
            legend pos = north west
            ]
            % Select appropriate columns
            \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

sub2.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}Screenshot_20210208_175745.png
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{file2.dat}{\tablea}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0, ymax=90,
            xmin=0, xmax=10,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            grid=major,
            legend entries={\(y_1\),\(y_2\),\(y_1+y_2\)},
            legend pos = north west
            ]
            % Select appropriate columns
            \addplot [blue, mark=*] table [x=x,y=y] {\tablea};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

As one might notice the left figure is slightly higher than the right figure, even though both figures were generated in the same way, and both figures have been set to the same width.

Comment: Did you try to fix `width` and `height` in `pgfplots`? If they don't have the same `height` even fixing the same `width` in `includestandalone` they won't have same size.

Comment: @Ignasi: Of course I could just set the width and height to fixed values, but by doing that I either might damage the aspect ratio of the figure, and will loose flexibility (i.e. if I have to scale the images a bit differently, I have to scale everything accordingly)

Comment: To align pgfplots, see group plots (p 454), scale only axis (p 294), and the various trim options (p 383).  Another trick is to increase the bounding box for every plot to a common size by adding points outside.